# Flutter / RiverPod 2.0 - AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily - does it support 'select'?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I'm trying the new RiverPod 2.0 AsyncNotifier provide, like...

```
final asyncHabitTrackingProvider =  AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily<AsyncHabitTrackingNotifier,HabitTrackingModel, int>(AsyncHabitTrackingNotifier.new);
```

However, this type of provider does not seem to support the 'select'suffix, like...

```
final aHabit = ref.watch(asyncHabitTrackingProvider .select((model) => model.habit));
```

Is this correct? If so, how do I access parts of the model returned by the provider?

Comment: If you have a family provider, I believe you have to give the family value first, and then you can add the .select

Comment: Looking at the API docs (https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/AsyncNotifierProviderFamily-class.html) there doesn't seem to be a select method

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything. Here is the code to prove it:

```dart
class HabitTrackingModel {}

final asyncHabitTrackingProvider = AutoDisposeAsyncNotifierProviderFamily<
    AsyncHabitTrackingNotifier,
    HabitTrackingModel,
    int>(AsyncHabitTrackingNotifier.new);

class AsyncHabitTrackingNotifier
    extends AutoDisposeFamilyAsyncNotifier<HabitTrackingModel, int> {

  @override
  FutureOr<HabitTrackingModel> build(int arg) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

Later, in the widget's build method:

```
  Widget build(context, ref) {
    ref.watch(asyncHabitTrackingProvider(5).select((value) => null));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response.    The problem I see with the pattern as you have outlined is that any widgets that want to use ref.watch(asyncHabitTrackingProvider(5).select((value) => null));  ... now have to somehow know that '5' is the family value.   To achieve this would require passing the value '5' down to all the widgets that would want to call 'select'.

Comment: Yes, that's how it's supposed to work. All widgets that use `select` must know the argument -- either pass the argument through a constructor or get it in another provider. There's nothing we can do about it.